# trying to turn a list of strings into a list of a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, split

I have a very long .txt file of bbcoded data.  I've split each sampling of data into a separate item in a list:

```
import re

file = open('scratch.txt', 'r')
file = file.read()

# split each dial into a separate entry in list
alldials = file.split('\n\n')

adials = []i
for dial in alldials:
    re.split('b|d|c', dial)
    adials.append(dial)

print(adials[1])
print(adials[1][8])
```

so that prints a string of data and the 9th character in the string. But the string is not split by the letters used in the argument, or really split at all unless the print command specifically asks for that second index....

what I'd like to split it by are these strings:  '\s\s[b]', '[\b]', [dial], [\dial], [icon], and [\icon], but as I started running into problems, I simplified the code down more and more, to figure out what was going wrong, and now I'm as simple as I can make it and I guess I'm missunderstanding a fundamental part of split() or the re module.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there some sample (small) input data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `re.split` does not modify the string in place, it returns it as a new string, which means if you want to split it you should do something like this:

```
split_dial = re.split('b|d|c', dial)
adials.append(split_dial)
```

Comment: oh my gosh.  thank you.  can you help me with one more thing?  now the split is doing everything I want it to, except that it's not removing any brackets, [ ]?  its removing \ which surprises me, but still...

Comment: If you want to remove certain characters you can use the method `replace` of `strings`, which takes the character that you want to replace and the new character, for just deleting the character `[` this will work: `a_string.replace('[', '')`